# How to add more faces to triangular mesh

Tags: mesh, faces, edges, knife-tool, remesh

I need to add more faces to this selected part. I have tried adding edge loops but that won't work. I have tried the knife tool but that will take too much time to make, any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: It is not that big object, I would suggest you to separate this part of the object from the rest of the object, then take some cube and remodel it with quads, this way you can get your desire better... or one idea, try to press F3 and search for "Tris to Quads" It may not work, it may not change all triangles to quads, but maybe you will be lucky

Comment: Why knife tool takes too much time? How many more faces do you want to add? What's the logic behind added faces, that is, why do you need to add them?

Comment: if your right click > Subdivide it will add triangles, but do you want to keep triangles?

Comment: @MikoCG tris to quads didn't work but my problem solved with subdivide

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I need a smooth face for 3d printing

Comment: Adding more faces without actually moving the geometry around won’t make the surface any smoother. If you use the Smooth operator however, it will smooth, but you’ll have to restrict the axes or something to keep the knife from them becoming dull.